# How to distinguish between a class and an interface in Kotlin using KClass reflection

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I am using Kotlins KClass to find classes by name like this:

```
val i: KClass<*> = Class.forName("SampleClass").kotlin
```

However, I want to omit interfaces. So far I am distinguishing interfaces from classes by the constructor.

```
val i: KClass<*> = Class.forName(input).kotlin

if (i.constructors.isEmpty()){
    println("This is an interface")
}else{
    println("This is a class")
}
```

I don't think that it is very clean. I am looking for something along the lines of

```
i.isInterface
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Are you reusing this code multiple times? If so, try making your own `i.isInterface()` function.

Comment: Not the answer but why not simply use SampleClass::class for getting the KClass

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I am passing the name of the class as an argument which is a String. Doing `input::class` returns the details for the String class instead of what I am actually looking for.

Comment: @fin444 I actually did. The snippet above is just an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that the constructors counting solution might not be very precise for general purpose use. For example, Kotlin package facade classes do not have any constructors either, but they are not interfaces (UPD: and their constructors cannot even be reflected with `kotlin-reflect`, just as those of anonymous classes, `KFunction` and maybe more).

There's no function/property in `kotlin-reflect` that allows a straightforward check. On JVM, you can do it as `i.java.isInterface` or make an extension:

```
val KClass<*>.isInterface get() = java.isInterface
```