# How to obtain superclass of a reflected class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, reflection, superclass

If Kotlin disallows multiple inheritance, then why [`KClass<*>.superclasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/superclasses.html) return a list? How to find that single superclass?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, `superclasses` contains [immediate superclasses of this class, in the order they are listed in the source code. Includes superclasses and **superinterfaces** of the class, but does not include the class itself](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/superclasses.html).

A Kotlin `class` may in fact only inherit from a single super class, but may implement several super interfaces.

Borrowing from a [different question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48568776/3160089) on StackOverflow, something like the following might work. However, I did not test this.

```kotlin
val KClass<*>.isInterface: Boolean
    get() = java.isInterface

val KClass<*>.superclass: KClass<*> 
    get() = superclasses.filterNot { it.isInterface }.single()
```

Comment: But what `java` is doing here? Wouldn't it filter out only Java interfaces?

Comment: @Dims It accesses the underlying Java `Class`, thus only works when working with Kotlin/JVM. A `interface` created in Kotlin should result in a Java `Class` where `isInterface` is true. Instead of relying on `java.isInterface`, you might use  `KClass.isAbstract` instead, to filter out `interface`s. However, this would also filter out `abstract class`es I assume.